# Error in Displaying Image using Php and mysql through folder and mysql url

Tags: php, mysql

im storing image in a folder using php and saving the name url in mysql and i need to display from the folder using the saved url in mysql database., i tried the following but facing error in display.. images are saving on the folder while upload. but displaying it getting broken images..

insert.php

```
<form action="imagebackend.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-
data">
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" cellpadding="3"   
bordercolor="#cccccc">
<tr>
<td>File:</td>
<td><input type="file" name="filep" size=45></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan=2><p align="center">
<input type="submit" name="action" value="Load">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

<?php
if ($_POST["action"] == "Load")
{
$folder = "C:/wamp/www/userlogin/pic/";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filep"]["tmp_name"]   
,"$folder".$_FILES["filep"]["name"]);
echo "<p align=center>File ".$_FILES["filep"]["name"]."loaded...";
$result = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die ("Could not    
save image name Error: " . mysql_error());
mysqli_select_db($result, "login") or die("Could not select database");
mysqli_query($result, "INSERT into picture (ul)   
VALUES('".$_FILES['filep']['name']."')");
if($result) { echo "Image name saved into database"; }
else {
//Gives and error if its not
echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
}
}
?>
```

and display.php

```
<?php
//Retrieves data from MySQL
$conn= mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die ("Could not save 
image name Error: " . mysql_error());
mysqli_select_db($conn, "login") or die("Could not select database");
$data = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT ul FROM picture") or
die(mysqli_error());
//Puts it into an array
$file_path = "C:/wamp/www/userlogin/pic/";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)) 
{//Outputs the image and other data
$src=$file_path.$row['ul'];
echo '<img src=".$src."><br>';
echo"no images found";
}
?>
```

kindly help me on this .,
im getting a broken image
i tried a lot im wasting my time for 3 days on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your code...

**insert.php**

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" cellpadding="3" bordercolor="#cccccc">
   <tr>
       <td>File:</td>
       <td><input type="file" name="filep" size=45></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td colspan=2><p align="center"><input type="submit" name="action" value="Load"></td>
   </tr>
</table>
</form>

<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
   $folder = "userlogin/pic/";
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filep"]["tmp_name"], $folder . $_FILES["filep"]["name"]);
   echo "<p align=center>File ".$_FILES["filep"]["name"]."loaded...";
   $result = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die ("Could not save image name Error: " . mysql_error());
   mysqli_select_db($result, "login") or die("Could not select database");
   $fileName = $_FILES['filep']['name'];
   mysqli_query($result, "INSERT into picture(ul)VALUES('$fileName')");
   if($result) { 
       echo " Image name saved into database";
   }else {
       //Gives and error if its not
       echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
   }
}
?>
```

**display.php**

```
<?php
//Retrieves data from MySQL
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die ("Could not save image name Error: " . mysql_error());
mysqli_select_db($conn, "login") or die("Could not select database");
$data = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT ul FROM picture") or die(mysqli_error());
//Puts it into an array
$file_path = "userlogin/pic/";
if(mysqli_num_rows($data) > 0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
        //Outputs the image and other data
        $src= $file_path . $row['ul']; ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $src; ?>"><br/>
    <?php }
}else{
    echo"no images found";
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi malik thank you so much the code which u given me is working fine thanks yar., really in need a coffee now..  file path i gave this $file_path = "http://localhost/userlogin/pic/";   in display.php

Answer (score 1):

You should user Website url rather than path of actual server folder.

Use

```
$file_path = "http://localhost/userlogin/pic/";
```

Comment: hi pratik c joshi ., I tried it but same result., thanks for ur comments ., can u find where im going wrong still??

Comment: inside Web browser : paste your url like : `http://localhost/userlogin/pic/YOUR_IMAGE_NAME.JPG` so you get to know how should you access url and which is correct path

Answer (score 0):

First check if uploaded correct or not like this

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filep"]["tmp_name"], $folder . $_FILES["filep"]["name"])) {

}
else {

}
```

if upload success then u can insert mysql other wise else part

Comment: Hi ganesan ., i used ur code the images are moving successfully .. also in those folders its saving successfully..                                                                                                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filep"]["tmp_name"], $folder .               $_FILES["filep"]["name"])) 
    {
     echo "images moved sus";
    }
    else {
    echo "not done";
    }          but same result

Comment: can u check file permission of the image. if not, use

chmod($uri,0664)

and also check folder perm